# Are there any penalties for using hints?

Tags: lara-croft-go

Yesterday, I got utterly frustrated with one of the Shard of Life puzzles and used a "Hint". I was expecting some sort of vague tip like "go for the second enemy first" or something. Instead, I was literally given a step-by-step path to complete the level.

It felt like cheating, honestly. Is there any penalty for using Hints? Do the vases not show up while using them or something?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference that I'm playing on PS4, rather than Android/iOS, but I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to **[this guide](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/lara-croft-go/301326-lara-croft-go-trophy-guide-roadmap.html)** there are absolutely no penalties linked to using hints.

The previous game (Hitman GO) had a trophy that required you to play the entire game without using hints and on some levels using hints would stop you from gaining other trophies, however this is not the case anymore in Lara Croft GO.

Comment: Wow, I really feel like there should be some sort of penalty for using those "hints"... oh well, good to know!

Comment: @Vemonus I've only played Hitman go on android and well the biggest penalty was... money (and me feeling guilty when using them). I mean android achievements aren't really that important to me...

Comment: On iOS, Hitman GO has an achievement which requires hints. “*Hint Rebel: Use a hint, ignore the instructions but finish the level anyway.*”